# Read/Write from/to database on the iphone. (Database is on a server)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite, core-data

I want the user of my app to interact with the database. So he is allowed both, to read and write data to and from the database. How would I do that if my sqlite database is not in the mainBundle but on a server ? 
And : Is it generally better to use Core Data over Sqlite ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't make direct connections to remote databases. What you'll do is create a web service that lives on the same server as the database and exposes an interface to it. So the iPhone talks to the web service (maybe using NSURLConnection), and the web service talks to the database.

And yes, Core Data is always better than Sqlite.

Comment: Ok thank you, ... Another question: Is setting up a Core Data database comparably more difficult or easier ? How would a "Web service" talk to the Core Data database ?

Comment: @user1066899, There will be a learning curve to Core Data if you're used to Sqlite, but there are plenty of tutorials out there to help you. Once you're comfortable with it, it will have been well worth the effort.

Comment: The web service doesn't talk directly to the Core Data Model either. The interaction between the iPhone and the service is mediated by a URL connection, which boils down to exchanging data. The phone will make a request to the service. The service will respond to the client with data. The client will do as it wishes with the data, including writing it to Core Data.

Comment: Ok got that. Unfortunately, there is no "Use Core Data" option with a view-based application anymore. Are there many steps to achieve that manually ? I have to add the `CoreData` Framework obviously, but besides that, which steps have to be taken ?

Comment: @user1066899, setting it up manually is probably harder than just starting with one of the templates that does support Core Data: Empty Application, Utility Application, or Master-Detail Application.

Comment: All right. Thanks very much :) I did not really figure out what you meant with the "service by a URL connection", but you helped me a lot anyway!